# Copy single file from projects base directory as asset

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, build, assets

I want to copy one single file (`package.json`) from my projects root directory to my projects `assets` directory when building. To do this I have tried to configure the `assets` section of the `angular.json` file multiple times. I have tried

```
{
  "glob": "package.json",
  "input": "./",
  "output": "assets"
}
// or
{
  "glob": "package.json",
  "input": "./",
  "output": "./assets"
}
// or
{
  "glob": "package.json",
  "input": "",
  "output": "assets"
}
```

and so on but none of this variants would work. It also does not seem to be the problem that I want to copy `package.json`, because it does not work for `README.md` either.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: i guess you are trying wrong paths as `package.json` is in project root but build process uses application root as base for resolving paths try adding few `../`

Comment: Using something like `{"input":"node_modules/xyz",... }` works just fine. So I thought it must be using the projects root. But I'll try that!